# SonataAdminBundle, filtering by function result

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

In my Symfony project I'm using SonataAdminBundle. And I got a question:
For example I have some entity with a function:

```
class Entity {
protected $id;

public idBiggerThan($value) {
     return $id > $value;
}
```

And I want to create a filter that filters list by the result of this function (for example to be able choose only entities that have id bigger that current user).

I understand that this filter can be written without using this function, but I have much more complex functions, for which I don't want to write queries.

Thanks for your help.

**UPD:** I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
$datagridMapper
    ->add('id', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
        'callback' => 
            function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value['value']) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder
                    ->where($alias . '. idBiggerThan(:current_user)')
                    ->setParameter('current_user', $this->getCurrentUser()->getId());

            },
        'field_type' => 'checkbox'
    ));
```

Comment: You can create your own filter types what ever your criteria is i have created one for my own needs to have number range filter [`Sonata-admin-number-range-filter`](https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-admin-number-range-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on doctrine_orm_callback in the documentation:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html

```
    $datagridMapper->add('title')
                ->add('enabled')
                ->add('tags', null, array(), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
                ->add('author')
                ->add('with_open_comments', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
    //                'callback'   => array($this, 'getWithOpenCommentFilter'),
                    'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                        if (!$value['value']) {
                            return;
                        }
                        $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.comments', $alias), 'c');
                        $queryBuilder->andWhere('c.status = :status');
                        $queryBuilder->setParameter('status', Comment::STATUS_MODERATE);
                        return true;
                    },
                    'field_type' => 'checkbox'
                ));
```